# java <String> tag with objects?

Tags: java

So, while looking through others code ive been seeing things like  such as in the following code:

```
List myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
```

What exactly does this do? I haven't been able to find any documentation, in part by the reason that I don't really know what it is called. And if possible an explanation of what exactly they do?

Comment: This is called generics. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/

Comment: It is the type of data you want to put inside the `Collection`. The compiler would now check, if you are putting in the correct type of data as defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That particular code generates a list that contains the entries resulted from splitting the **s** string at each space.

The < String> defines the generic type for the List, and the advantage (among other ones) is that you can call myList.get(index) and not have to cast it to a String.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic.  You are instantiating an ArrayList that stores String objects.